# 'Segmentation fault' as user doesn't has an input

Tags: c, cs50

I wanted to implement a program that changes the user his DNA-string to a RNA-string. But I have some problems with my code that I don't really understand. My code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])

{
    int n = strlen(argv[1]);

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./rna ATGC\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (argc == 2 && n >= 4)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (argv[1][i] == 'A' || argv[1][i] == 'a')
            {
                printf("U");
            }
            else if (argv[1][i] == 'G' || argv[1][i] == 'g')
            {
                printf("C");
            }
            else if (argv[1][i] == 'C' || argv[1][i] == 'c')
            {
                printf("G");
            }
            else if (argv[1][i] == 'T' || argv[1][i] == 't')
            {
                printf("A");
            }
        }
    return 0;
    }
    if (n <= 3)
    {
        printf("Invalid DNA\n");
    }

}
```

If the user just runs the program I want to get an output like this:

```
$ ./rna
Usage: ./rna ATGC
```

But, I get this and can't really figure out what is wrong.

```
$ ./rna
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: If no arguments are passed then `argv[1]` is a NULL pointer and your first line does `strlen(NULL)` which is undefined behavior (segfault in this case).  You should move `n=strlen(argv[1])` inside the `argc == 2` block.

Comment: By the way, all your `if (argv[1][i] == 'A' ...)` would be much neater inside a function that returns the complementary character, and uses `switch` instead.

Comment: `string` is non-standard. Please tag your post with `cs50` so we don't have to see the bad practice of hiding pointers using typedefs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n = strlen(argv[1]);
```

if there are no command-line arguments it invokes undefined behaviour.

change to:

```
size_t n = argc > 1 ? strlen(argv[1]) : 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your checking the length (`argc`) of `argv` *after* accessing the element that does not exist. You cannot do `strlen(argv[1])` before you're sure there *is* an `argv[1]`!